# Form from two distinct models

Tags: python, django, forms, models

I need to create 1 contact form from multiple models which looks like this :

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, primary_key=True)
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=16, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Customer_messages(models.Model):
    email = models.ForeignKey(Customer)
    message = models.TextField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email
```

my problem is that i need to create one form from theese two models which should have name, email, phone number and message. You can see that models are connected via email address which is also primary key. Can you help me with this situation?

currently my form looks something like this :

```
class CustomerContactFrom(forms.ModelForm):
name = forms.CharField(max_length=128, help_text="Meno: ")
email = forms.EmailField(max_length=254, help_text="Email: ")
phone_number = forms.CharField(max_length=16, help_text='Telefónne číslo: ')

class Meta:
    model = Customer
```

but how to add next textarea for message and when posted save it to DB?

Thanks.

Comment: will you create new `Customer_messages` on every form submit or edit a certain one?

Comment: new one on every submit

Answer (score 0):

```
class CustomerContactFrom(forms.ModelForm):
    message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.widgets.Textarea())

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'phone_number')

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        instance = super(CustomerContactFrom, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        new_message = Customer_messages.objects.create(email=instance,
                                   message=self.cleaned_data['message'])

        return instance
```

This form will do the job.

Suggestion: `Customer_messages` should `CustomerMessage', Camel-case writing and not plural.`email`field of`Customer_messages`model should be`customer` because it is referance to customer. These are just suggestion :)